# Open IE Browser Window

Tags: python, internet-explorer, browser

The [`webbrowser` library](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) provides a convenient way to launch a URL with a browser window through the `webbrowser.open()` method. Numerous browser types are available, but there does not appear to be an explicit way to launch Internet Explorer when running python on windows.

`WindowsDefault` only works if Internet Explorer is set as the default browser, which is not an assumption I can make.

Is there a way to explicitly launch a URL into Internet Explorer without reverting to windows API calls?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to launch IE?

Comment: The page I am launching is a local ms-office generated html file that uses horrible markup which only IE can understand properly.  This will be an internal script, so user autonomy not an issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

More elegant code:

```
import webbrowser

ie = webbrowser.get(webbrowser.iexplore)
ie.open('google.com')
```

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> ie = webbrowser.get('c:\\program files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe')
>>> ie.open('http://google.com')
True
```

Comment: I keep getting 'Error: could not locate runnable browser'

Answer (score 8):

```
iexplore = os.path.join(os.environ.get("PROGRAMFILES", "C:\\Program Files"),
    "Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE")
ie = webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(iexplore)
ie.open(...)
```

This is what the `webrowser` module uses internally.

Comment: Does not works in background. It always opens the page. I in fact tried doing ie.Visible=0 still does not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can always do something like

```
subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" http://www.example.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" www.google.com')
```

Comment: Keep in mind that non-english versions of Windows keep name its `Program Files` folder differently. `Archivos de Programa`, for example in spanish. You should use `%PROGRAMFILES%` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to use the script in more than your machine, keep in mind that not everyone has a English version of Windows

```
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.Popen(r'"' + os.environ["PROGRAMFILES"] + '\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try putting the absolute path of internet explorer exe file in your code.

```
ie=webbrowser.get("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")
ie.open_new("http://google.com")
```