# Launch IPython notebook with selected browser

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, ipython

I am trying to start IPython with a non default browser (in my case Firefox)
and thought I could replicate the replicate the script given [in this blog](http://www.libertypages.com/clarktech/?p=3357)

**I am on Windows 7**

I put the following code in a file say "module.py"

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("ipython notebook --no-browser", shell=True)
subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe', '-new-tab', 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/'])
```

However when I run it from the command line

```
 python C:\Users\mugabal\Desktop\module1.py
```

It execute the first line but not the second one (both lines work fine individually)

My question (in a more general term) how can I launch a process and tell it not to highjack the console window?

I apologize in advance if I have overseen an obvious explanation but I looked both in the subprocess documentation and on this platform

**----- UPDATE -----**

I should have added that I tried to launch IPython with selected browser but could not figure out how to get it work

```
>ipython notebook --browser='C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe'
... 
[NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
...
**[NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.**
```

To be precise, the following command in a Windows command prompt window works as expected:

```
start firefox
```

but

```
ipython notebook --browser=firefox
```

does not work (same error as above).

Comment: `ipython notebook --browser=firefox` worked for me, thanks!

Comment: If you just want a separate icon in windows taskbar, login as guest in Chrome and launch jupyter notebook

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I had the same problem on windows and got it work this way:

- Create a config file with command
  `ipython profile create default`
- Edit ipython_notebook_config.py file, search for line

`#c.NotebookApp.browser =''`

and replace it with

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'firefox'
```

then it works for me.

Hope it will help you.

JPG

Comment: I had to add use u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe' to make it work

Comment: Yes! It works for jupyter notebook. only set "c.NotebookApp.browser = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'  " doesn't work for chrome, but works well for firefox, which is really strange bug. Your solution solves the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Just a note for those who are using macOS: this works, but of course the path is different. You can link to the applications folder: `/Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOs/Opera`.

Comment: For Jupyter notebook, create config with command `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and edit the jupyter_notebook_config.py file as stated above

Answer (score 37):

On my mac, I got the following command to use Firefox instead of my default Chrome:

```
jupyter notebook --browser firefox
```

Comment: Thanks!  **Windows notice:** This works if the path to firefox is set in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a real answer. I just want to share with the less computer savvy what JPG's answer looks like step-by-step. Presumably, on Windows Explorer (screen capture attached below), the file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` is listed:

[image]

In my case, the directory for the file (on top menu of Explorer) was `C:\Users\My_name\.jupyter`

The second part of the answer can be implemented by simply pasting:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'firefox'
```

in the space on the space seen on the screen capture below, corresponding to the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` opened within PyCharm:

[image]

... only that I set it up to open in Opera:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('opera', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Opera\\launcher.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'opera'
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not use

```
--browser=<Unicode> (NotebookApp.browser)
    Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the
    notebook. If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the
   `webbrowser` standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I could not this to work (see update). How should the command look exactly ?

Comment: IIRC, and looking at the code, you should use the same syntax as webbrowser get : http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get so just ipython notebook --browser='firefox' on windows I guess

Comment: Did you tried escaping backslash and space ? We just forward the option to webbrowser.get, so if you achieve to make it work, you'll know the command you need to use

Comment: from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532884/open-ie-browser-window I would say that indeed you need to escape backslash, but not space.

Comment: Thanks. escaping do not work either. actually the problem could be the configuration of the PC when I run import webbrowser, print webbrowser._browsers, it shows only explorer

Comment: I've no clue as of why then. Good Luck

Comment: As Matt said, this solution works just fine: `--browser=<Unicode>` But be carefull. If you try for example: `--browser=u'firefox'` it doesn't work, you need to use double quotes: `--browser="firefox"`

Answer (score 5):

I uncomment this line and change into False, not to make ipython notebook open a web browser at start, so we can point the ipython notebook address in an active web browser.

```
# Whether to open in a browser after starting. The specific browser used is
# platform dependent and determined by the python standard library `webbrowser`
# module, unless it is overridden using the --browser (NotebookApp.browser)
# configuration option.
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```

Better still, I pin the address in my Firefox to make it active everytime I open the browser.

Answer (score 4):

to make it work with `brave` and `chrome` you need to append a `%s` param that represents the URL. Tested the following on Linux terminal and works great:

```sh
jupyter notebook --browser="google-chrome %s"
jupyter notebook --browser="brave-browser %s"
```

firefox doesn't need `%s`

```sh
jupyter notebook --browser=firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the environment variable BROWSER to the the executable of the browser (in my case Google Chrome), and Ipython Notebook started in the browser I liked.

```
PS H:\> $env:BROWSER = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
PS H:\> $env:BROWSER
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
PS H:\>
PS H:\> ipython notebook
2015-02-19 14:05:01.690 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: C:\\Users\\abc\\.ipython\\profile_default'
2015-02-19 14:05:01.832 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2015-02-19 14:05:01.901 [NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another random port.
2015-02-19 14:05:01.908 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: H:\
2015-02-19 14:05:01.908 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
2015-02-19 14:05:01.910 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/
2015-02-19 14:05:01.910 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the below code in command prompt it gives the result link which you can copy in any browser to open Jupiter notebook.

```
jupyter notebook --browser firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried what JPG and norfeldt suggested. It worked perfectly on my Windows 7 computer. Here is a copy of the modified section of  ipython_notebook_config.py (located under C:\Users\'your username'\.ipython to use Safari as the default browser for notebook. As norfeldt said, please notice the u before 'C:\...)

```
# c.NotebookApp.certfile = u''

import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('safari', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Safari\\safari.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'safari'
```

Answer (score -2):

Without coding, you can just set your default browser to Chrome or Firefox etc. It works for my windows system.