# open ipython notebook with firefox

Tags: firefox, ipython

I'm using Windows 10 and my default browser is Chrome.  If I go to the Firefox directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox) and open the command prompt and type:

```
ipython notebook --browser='firefox'
```

then the notebook opens as expected.  However if I navigate to the folder which contains my files and try to do something like:

```
ipython notebook --browser='C:\Program/Files/(x86)\Mozilla/Firefox\firefox'
```

then it does not launch.  The error is "No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser".  I have tried many variations of this with no success.  This was brought up in a similar thread a couple years ago ([Launch IPython notebook with selected browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632663/launch-ipython-notebook-with-selected-browser)) with no resolution that I could see.

Comment: First of all the path you wrote is missing spaces. If that's just a typo and not the cause of your problem, it sounds like a bug and you should post it to IPython's bugtracker.

Comment: There is no typo.  Using your advice I have tried many more variations including spaces with no success.  For example, I can use `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"` however `ipython notebook --browser="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox"` gives me the same error I have been getting.