# Is it possibly to pass options to Jupyter notebook when starting it from anaconda-navigator?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

Is there a way to pass (arbitrary) options to Jupyter notebook when starting it from anaconda-navigator? Is there some setting in AN (not in JN) to change this?

Background: Starting JN from AN menu opens the default browser, in my case Firefox (on Ubuntu). Unfortunately, Firefox has a problem with scrolling in the file list of JN (scroll slider jumps back to the top). Google-Chrome works, so I want to pass the option `--browser google-chrome` to JN. At the moment, I open my environment in AN, start a terminal for this environment, and run `jupyter notebook --browser google-chrome` (from a small script). That's a bit tedious. I didn't dare to change any JN config files (as recommended by https://stackoverflow.com/a/62786865/3852630). I also don't want to change the default browser. I'm working under Ubuntu.

(While we are at it: Is there an option for JN to set an initial directory for JN's file browser?)